# the macro may not be available in this workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've spent a lot of time reading through the various threads on this topic, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I pasted this code (after inserting a blank rectangle) into a new workbook, and it worked. But in my current workbook, the `tester` sub runs fine, but when I call `doStuff` from the button, it throws an error (outlined in the title of this question).

Ive checked security, and again, new workbook, same code, works perfectly. It can't be the macro doesn't exist, because the scope is very small, and I can see both subs.

```
Sub tester()
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "doStuff"

End Sub

Sub doStuff()

    MsgBox "hello"

End Sub
```

Comment: Where's the code located? Does it need to be declared as Public Sub?

Comment: *... or all macros may be disabled* is the continuation of your error message. It's probably not the case but it's good to know about it. If your `doStuff` procedure is in a standard module, e.g. `Module1`, then it should work as-is. If it's in a sheet module or the `ThisWorkbook` module, you will need to use something like `Sheet1.doStuff` or `ThisWorkbook.doStuff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to bind a macro to a shape, here is the code you are looking for:

```
Sub assign_macro_to_shape()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").OnAction = "doStuff"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign the "doDtuff" macro to the rectangle.  Right-click the rectangle and choose "assign macro" as seen here.  Then pick the "doStuff" macro.

[image]

Comment: That's what first 2 lines are doing. The '.onaction =' piece is assigning the macro directly to the shape.

Comment: If you are trying to write code to assign a macro to an object, that's different. I'll write a different.  I'll write another answer

Comment: You may find this surprising, but my entire ability to program in visual basic is because of you and your class. I regularly reference your VBA class, the structure, everything. You helped me discover the beauty and power of VBA. It was absolutely amazing. So glad we could coincidentally cross paths.

Comment: @JosephErickson, you are the first person I've come across who has found my course online.  It's very nice to meet you.  Did my other answer do what you are after?  If so, please mark it as the accepted answer.  If not, give more information in a comment and I'll try again

Comment: accepted the answer. I didn't take your course online. I took it in person in 2016.